# Separating signal from noise in similar frequency range

Tags: filters, noise

As shown in the figures, both of my signal and noise have the same frequency domain, how can I separate them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry . I mistake the picture. The left picture is the noise and right picture is the signal .

Comment: I've edited to display the images. So, what's on top and bottom ?

Comment: Answer upvotes and better answer validation are required for this question

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, it is quite unlikely that you can filter your data with a standard frequency filter, thus a linear filter.

Unless the signal and the noise are well separated in time, unless you have a model, you will probably need to resort to other techniques, such as nonlinear filtering, time-frequency or time-scale filtering, or add additional information or assumptions, such as thought signal or noise properties (to name a few: gaussianity, positivity, independence, sparsity), and bend to blind source separation, latent variable analysis, nonlinear matrix separation, etc.